# Convert Double To Long With Checks

Tags: double, long-integer

As you can see by the code below it should if out of range return the right long value without getting a random number when casting. However this code doesn't execute for the minimum value at all?

```
System.out.println(Double.MIN_VALUE < Long.MAX_VALUE);//this prints true so it should at the min value be in range meaning normal casting should work
public static long castLong(double d)
{
    if(d > Long.MAX_VALUE)
        return Long.MAX_VALUE;
    else if(d < Long.MIN_VALUE)
    {
        System.out.println("here");
        return Long.MIN_VALUE;
    }
    return (long)d;
}
```

based on the code above it should cast the issue is even when the values are in range it doesn't cast properly just goes to 0. So What am I suppose to do for said function make a double/float to string then how do I convert the string into long since it prints "4.9E-324". So what for the E fill with zeros? or what am I suppose to do to convert it in range of long max/min value when converting?

Comment: Does your compiler not warn you about comparing double to long?

Comment: No especially since it only prints 0. Same with using Math.round(Double.MIN_VALUE) returns 0. What I expect is Long.MIN_VALUE